# How can I define a parameter from specific columns and rows from excel?

Tags: excel, pandas, list, dataframe, xlsx

I want to obtain a list of certain values from an excel file.

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx')

orders = df[['Order']].loc[[4,129]]
print(orders)
```

I obtained this solution:

```
        Order
4    18292839
129  83938292
```

But the solution that I want to obtain is the orders from 4 to 129 in a list on values like this:

`['18292839', .............. (other orders), '83938292']`

If someone can help me I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orders.values.tolist()` to convert `pd.Series` into `list`. More about converting `DataFrames` and `Series` into the `list` you can read [here.](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-list/)